# Android unable to start Video Activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I have  statements in my application

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(movie1.getMovieWatchLink());
// With this line the Youtube application, if installed, will launch immediately.
// Without it you will be prompted with a list of the application to choose.
uri = Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+ uri.getQueryParameter("v"));
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri);
VideoActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
```

I'm passing youtube video URL

when i run the above statements,I'm not able to start the Activity,Could any one help me?

Comment: Do you have any logs?

Comment: yes,I debugged Here It is stopping VideoActivity.this.startActivity(intent);

Comment: Post your VideoActivity code..

Comment: I'm new to Andriod,Could you tell me after this line       VideoActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
Control will go to where?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code inside webview to loadurl

```
 <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/...." frameborder="0"     allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out this:

```
public class VideoWebview extends Activity {

    WebView webView;
    String htmlPre = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\"><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body style='margin:0; pading:0; background-color: black;'>";  
    String htmlCode = 
            " <embed style='width:100%; height:100%' src='http://www.platipus.nl/flvplayer/download/1.0/FLVPlayer.swf?fullscreen=true&video=@VIDEO@' " +
            "  autoplay='true' " +
            "  quality='high' bgcolor='#000000' " +
            "  name='VideoPlayer' align='middle'" + // width='640' height='480' 
            "  allowScriptAccess='*' allowFullScreen='true'" +
            "  type='application/x-shockwave-flash' " +
            "  pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' />" +
            "";
    String htmlPost = "</body></html>";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.videowebview); 

          String url= "Your url";
         System.out.println("url="+url);

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY); //thanks Patrick!

        htmlCode = htmlCode.replaceAll("@VIDEO@",url);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://fake/fake", htmlPre+htmlCode+htmlPost, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);  
    }
```